# undefined method `destory' for #<Post:0x007f2735fd3e88>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have error like this,but I think that my code is right

```
def destroy
    @post=Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_path
end
```

So what is wrong,because I have post with `params[:id]`

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo. You wrote `destory` somewhere when you meant `destroy`.

Comment: Awesome find.  We should type in some text editor with spell check for sure!